# Is there a recommended way to structure the Fund codes

Tags: python, excel, structure

I am looking to structure my date. I have a list of fund codes and each fund code has its own properties like, Fund type, Tax type, asset class traded, NAV Dates.

Preference is to use Excel followed by Python.

PS: I am very new to coding and I want to apply coding skills to structure my data rather than just maintaining an excel manually.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Check out pandas as a "python companion" to Excel: https://pandas.pydata.org -- the functions `to_excel()` and `read_excel()` are particularly useful.  You might also like this site: https://pbpython.com

Answer (score 0):

Using [openpyxl](https://realpython.com/openpyxl-excel-spreadsheets-python/), you could easily interface python with excel spreadsheets, However if you want an alternative solution you could use a [database](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html).